# Церковь - с прописной и строчной. Это я подняла первую, - правильно (ли)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, прописная-строчная

> Христианская церковь ещё в самом начале своего существования назначила
>   семь нотариусов, соответственно районам Рима. Эти летописцы вели
>   историю **Ц**еркви, и **ц**ерковь Святой Пуденцианы — один из
>   немногих бесспорных ранних памятников. Он называется во многих
>   источниках «первой из церквей Рима».

Ничего, что ***памятник называется*** во многих источниках «**первой из церквей** Рима»?

Comment: Что именно смущает?

Comment: Два момента: моя правка (у автора со строчной) и *памятник называется «первой из церквей».*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На Грамоте:

Нужно ли (и если нужно, почему) писать слово "церковь" с прописной буквы? Мы же не пишем с прописной "правительство". Пример контекста: "Его преследовала церковь".

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Слово *церковь* пишется с прописной буквы в двух случаях: 1) в значении "Божественное учреждение" в богословских текстах или если слову *церковь* в этом значении придается особый высокий смысл, например: *Отцы Церкви, Заповеди Церкви*; 2) вместо *Русская православная церковь*, например: *решение Церкви*. В значениях "храм" и "религиозная организация" слово *церковь* пишется со строчной буквы, например: *ходить в церковь, служить в церкви, отлучить от церкви, отделение церкви от государства*.
В Вашем примере корректно написание со строчной буквы.

Судя по логике Грамоты, в предложении *Эти летописцы вели историю Церкви* надо "Ц" (вели историю Церкви - сокращенное название Христианской церкви).

*и церковь Святой Пуденцианы — один из немногих бесспорных ранних памятников. Он называется во многих источниках «первой из церквей Рима».* Здесь, может быть,  автору следовало бы написать не "он", а "она", если речь идет о церкви Святой Пуденцианы.

Тогда: и церковь Святой Пуденцианы — один из немногих бесспорных ранних памятников. Она [церковь Святой Пуденцианы] называется во многих источниках «первой из церквей Рима»

Answer (score 0):

Слово церковь пишется с прописной буквы в двух случаях:

1) в значении 'Божественное учреждение' – в богословских текстах, а также если слову церковь в этом значении придается особый высокий смысл, например: Отцы Церкви, Заповеди Церкви;
2)   если слово Церковь используется вместо полного названия религиозной организации (например, вместо Русская православная церковь): решение Церкви.

В значениях 'храм' и 'религиозная организация' слово церковь пишется со строчной буквы, например: ходить в церковь, служить в церкви, отлучить от церкви, отделение церкви от государства.

В примере, который приводится в вопросе, требуется написание церковь со строчной буквы: Эти летописцы вели историю церкви, и церковь Святой Пуденцианы...

Answer (score 0):

1) **Эти летописцы вели историю Церкви, и церковь Святой Пуденцианы — один из немногих бесспорных ранних памятников.**

Здесь Церковь — сокращенное название религиозной организации: **Христианская церковь или Церковь.**

Из Википедии: **Христиа́нская це́рковь**  — религиозное сообщество христиан, объединённых общей верой в Иисуса Христа как Бога и Спасителя, который есть создатель **Церкви** и её Глава. В экклезиологии под **Церковью** понимается сообщество христиан прошлого и настоящего.

2) **Памятник называют первой из церквей Рима**. Нет согласования в роде.

Эти летописцы вели историю Церкви, и церковь Святой Пуденцианы — один из немногих бесспорных ранних памятников, при этом во многих источниках **ее** называют «первой из церквей Рима».